# How do you debug your Fleetboard Android app?

Tags: fleetboard

Where do you debug/emulate your Fleetboard app?

Do you use standart android tablem emulator in landscape orientation?

How then do you invoke Fleetboard SDK functions to mock real truck device?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard Android emulator to run and debug your app but Vehicle related APIs won't be available within this Environment. If you want to test your app including the usage of VehicleAPI you must run your app on a Fleetboard Test Device. On These devices we provide a Simulator that mocks real Vehicle Data and allows you to debug this Szenario.
Test devices can be ordered by contacting buildapps@daimler.com